# Assigning data frame name to all rows in a column

Tags: r

I want to add the data frame name to all the rows in a column, for each data frame in a list.

Dummy data:

```
test_df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = c("a","b","c","d","e"))
```

What I want to end up with is this:

```
x    y    ref
1    a    test_df
2    b    test_df
3    c    test_df
4    d    test_df
5    e    test_df
```

The reason is that I am going to rbind multiple data frames later, and I want to be able to filter on which data frame the values came from. I tried the following:

```
library(dplyr)

test <- function(df) {
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(ref = deparse(substitute(df)))
  return(df)
}
```

But this only creates a column named ref with the value "df" in each row. Any suggestions with dplyr is greatly appreciated. Or maybe is there a way to directly create this column in the rbind-call?

Comment: Have a look at the `.id` argument of `dplyr::bind_rows()`. You might try this: `bind_rows(your_list, .id = "ref")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, try this:

```
library(lazyeval)
test <- function(df) {
   df <- df %>% mutate(ref = expr_label(df))
   return(df)
 }
test(test_df)
  x y       ref
1 a `test_df`
2 b `test_df`
3 c `test_df`
4 d `test_df`
5 e `test_df`
```

Alternatively, this also works, but does not use `dplyr`:

```
test2 <- function(df) {
  df$ref <- deparse(substitute(df))
  return(df)
}
test2(test_df)
  x y     ref
1 1 a test_df
2 2 b test_df
3 3 c test_df
4 4 d test_df
5 5 e test_df
```

---

To make this work with lists of dataframes and `lapply` is trickier due to how `lapply` works, but following workaround works:

```
test_df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = c("a","b","c","d","e"))
test_df2 <- data.frame(x = 11:15, y = c("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"))
```

Here I create a named list of dataframes:

```
dfs <- setNames(list(test_df, test_df2), c("test_df", "test_df2"))
dfs
$test_df
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 d
5 5 e

$test_df2
   x  y
1 11 aa
2 12 bb
3 13 cc
4 14 dd
5 15 ee
```

Now I change the helper function to accept the name as an argument:

```
test3 <- function(df, nm) {
  df$ref <- nm
  return(df)
}
```

Here I only pass the names to `lapply` and retrieve each dataframe from the named list `dfs` that I have defined above.

```
lapply(names(dfs), function(x) test3(dfs[[x]], x))
[[1]]
  x y     ref
1 1 a test_df
2 2 b test_df
3 3 c test_df
4 4 d test_df
5 5 e test_df

[[2]]
   x  y      ref
1 11 aa test_df2
2 12 bb test_df2
3 13 cc test_df2
4 14 dd test_df2
5 15 ee test_df2
```

That is not the most elegant way, but it works.

Having said that, if you want to combine the dataframes into one single dataframe, there is not much to add to @markus's suggestion of using `bind_rows`, as in

```
bind_rows(dfs, .id="ref")
        ref  x  y
1   test_df  1  a
2   test_df  2  b
3   test_df  3  c
4   test_df  4  d
5   test_df  5  e
6  test_df2 11 aa
7  test_df2 12 bb
8  test_df2 13 cc
9  test_df2 14 dd
10 test_df2 15 ee
```

Comment: I like the base version more. Less typing and less dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for reply. For me however, when I use this with lapply over the list of data frames, the column "ref" only contains the value 'x[[i]]'

Comment: @coffeinjunky As I say in the first line: "I want to add the data frame name to all the rows in a column, for each data frame in a list", sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 3):

> The reason is that I am going to rbind multiple data frames later, and
>   I want to be able to filter on which data frame the values came from.

Then just use `dplyr::bind_rows` with the `.id` parameter:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df_list,.id="name")
# works also : purrr::map_dfr(df_list,identity,.id="name")
# works also : data.table::rbindlist(df_list,idcol="name")

#   name x y
# 1    A 1 a
# 2    A 2 b
# 3    B 1 a
# 4    B 2 b
# 5    C 1 a
# 6    C 2 b
```

If your `data.frames` are not in a list already, note that `tibble::lst` will name the elements when you add them to a list, e.g `lst(df_A,df_B,df_C)`

Your example case is thus solved by `bind_rows(lst(test_df),.id="name")`

**data**

```
test_df <- data.frame(x = 1:2, y = c("a","b"))
df_list <- setNames(replicate(3,test_df,FALSE),LETTERS[1:3])
# $A
# x y
# 1 1 a
# 2 2 b
# 
# $B
# x y
# 1 1 a
# 2 2 b
# 
# $C
# x y
# 1 1 a
# 2 2 b
```